# сдвиг ячейки по таблице

Tags: html, css

как можно сдвинуть кнопку отправить в самое право внутри таблицы (через флоат не хочет)
https://jsfiddle.net/gmg0jna4/1/

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input id="call_me_question" type="text" name="question"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input id="call_me_name" type="text" name="name_call_me"/>
    </td>
</tr>                        
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input id="call_me_phone_code" type="text" name="phone_call_me_code"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="call_me_phone" type="text" name="phone_call_me"/>
    </td>                                    
</tr>
<tr colspan="3">
    <td>
        <input id="call_me_btn" type="submit" name="send_btn_call_me" value="send"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: а если они мне не нужны, я пробовал растянуть ячейку с кнопкой на ширину таблицы через colspan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

colspan="3" надо применять для ячейки, а не рядка. Добавьте вашей ячейке text-align и кнопка переместится.

https://jsfiddle.net/tdsctqbq/

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="call_me_question" type="text" name="question" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="call_me_name" type="text" name="name_call_me" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input id="call_me_phone_code" type="text" name="phone_call_me_code" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="call_me_phone" type="text" name="phone_call_me" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="text-align:right;">
      <input id="call_me_btn" type="submit" name="send_btn_call_me" value="send" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```